# Is the Interior of Hyperbola homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{2}}$?

Tags: general-topology

I know that the interior of the unit disk is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ by the mapping $(r,\theta)\to(\tan(\frac{r\pi}{2}),\theta)$. I am struggling to come up with a homeomorphic map from the interior of the hyperbola $x^{2}-y^{2}=1$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or to the interior of the unit disk. I think I am struggling mainly because I cannot find suitable coordinates to describe the interior. For example in the unit disk I just could write it as $r<1$.

By interior of the hyperbola I mean $\{(x,y):x^{2}-y^{2}<1\}$

Can anybody help me with a map from it to the disk or to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

I am very very new to homeomorphisms (Just about learnt the definitions).

Comment: Finding such coordinates has always been a nuisance for me, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be your region. If $(x,y)\in H$, then $x\in\left(-\sqrt{y^2+1},\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)$. And, given $a>0$, a homeomorphism between $(-a,a)$ and $\Bbb R$ is the one defined by$$\begin{array}{ccc}(-a,a)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&\dfrac x{1-\left|\frac xa\right|}.\end{array}\tag1$$So, consider\begin{array}{ccc}H&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\(x,y)&\mapsto&\left(\dfrac x{1-\left|\frac x{\sqrt{y^2+1}}\right|},y\right).\end{array}

---

Another possibility is to consider$$\begin{array}{ccc}(-a,a)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)\end{array}$$instead of $(1)$, which leads to\begin{array}{ccc}H&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\(x,y)&\mapsto&\left(\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{2\sqrt{y^2+1}}\right),y\right).\end{array}

Comment: can I just ask. What was wrong with the tan

Comment: Nothing. But the new version is more elementary.

Comment: Can you please also add it in the answer?. I find dealing with tan easier than |x|

Comment: It's done now.${}$

Comment: Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Can I use $g(x,y)=\left(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+y^{2}}}),y\right)$ ? . I am sorry but your $-\sqrt{1+y^{2}}<x<\sqrt{1+y^{2}}$ Opened my mind and suddenly a whole lot of functions are rushing in.

Comment: It's *me* that should have written that (as I did in my first version of my answer). Forget $\arctan$; it's $\tan$ that I should have used here!

Comment: Thanks again !!!!

Comment: This seems like possibly an occasion to wich the `\intertext{}` command in LaTeX could be used in MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*
For a **conformal** parameterization, study the [well-known picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_conic_sections)

[image: picture]

made up of confocal hyperbolas and ellipses.